# Generate a dynamic SCSS variable by appending another variable

Tags: html, css, sass, dynamic-variables

I'm trying to assign different colors to similar items using an SCSS `@for` loop. Can I append the `$i` variable used in the `@for` loop to `$color-`?

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>World</h1>
  <h1>Goodbye</h1>
</div>
```

```
$color-1: red;
$color-2: blue;
$color-3: yellow;

@for $i from 1 to 3 {
  div>h1:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    color: $color-{$i};
  }
}
```

Comment: Is my answer good enough for you, or do you still care about dynamic variable names?

Comment: Yes, your answer accomplishes the intent of what I'm trying to do! SCSS lists is a good thing to study up on, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about dynamic variable names, but the standard way to achieve what you want is SCSS lists, over which you can iterate.

```
$colors-list: red blue yellow;

@each $current-color in $colors-list {
    $i: index($colors-list, $current-color);
    div>h1:nth-child(#{$i}) { 
        color: $current-color;
    }
}
```

which compiles to

```
div > h1:nth-child(1) {
  color: red;
}

div > h1:nth-child(2) {
  color: blue;
}

div > h1:nth-child(3) {
  color: yellow;
}
```